# draw extend of print composer map as rectangle in canvas

Tags: qgis, print-composer

After defining the extend of my printed map in the printcomposer I can show the map center in the canvas by hitting "view extend in map canvas". So far so good. But is it also possible to show the exact **extend** with all borders? Or even better: map composer extend is shown as rectangle in the canvas.

At the moment I get that result by copying the coordinates of the map-composer extend to a txt-file (;-sparated), import it to the canvas and connect the points as polygon. But if I change the extend of the print composers map, I have to do all steps again. So is there a other way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible (although a plugin could be made to do this). Do you mind filing a feature request at http://hub.qgis.org and I'll try and tackle it for 2.6?